# How to convert Datetime into SAS format

Tags: sas

I am working with a huge number of observations in different tables in different versions.

I will use a date `%let date_to_view = "20JAN2014:16:10"dt;`
But how to convert this date into SAS format?

I knew how to Convert SAS data type (use proc sql):

```
dhms("01JAN1970'd,3,0,i.valid_dttm/1000) format datetime20.
```

I see date `20JAN2014:16:34:10` is `1390224849927` but how to convert it into code?

Comment: The dateTIME value that you posted does not match the integer value that you posted. The number you have posted is way too large. That particular time in Jan 2014 should have a stored value of only 1,705,854,850.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your formula `dhms("01JAN1970'd,3,0,i.valid_dttm/1000)` you are converting a number that represents the number of milliseconds since 01JAN1970 to a SAS datetime value that represents the number of seconds since 01JAN1960.  You also appear to be adding 3 hours.

So it sounds like your question is how to convert a SAS DATETIME value into a Unix timestamp value. So just reverse the arithmetic.

Your formula to convert from a Unix timestamp to a SAS datetime was:

```
sasdt2 = '01JAN1970:00:00'dt + '03:00't + unix_timestamp2/1000 ;
```

So to convert from a SAS datetime value to a Unix timestamp use:

```
unix_timestamp1 = 1000*(sasdt1 - '01JAN1970:00:00'dt - '03:00't) ;
```

Comment: oh thanks. I am not as good at formats Unix and etc. But it will be 1.39022249E12 how to format it into  '1390224849927'?

Comment: The format only matter when you are printing it. It does not change the value stored. You just need to count the number of digits you need. Length('1390224849927') is 13. So if you use a format of 13. (also known as F13.). Or anything longer will work also.

Answer (score 1):

"20JAN2014:16:10"dt is already in the correct SAS date (datetime) format, but as a date literal. SAS stores this as a number, representing the number of seconds since 01JAN1960:00:00:00.

If you just want the date component of the datetime, use the `datepart()` function, and format the result accordingly, e.g. `date9.`.

```
data want ;
  dt = "20JAN2014:16:10"dt ;
  date = datepart(dt) ;
  format dt datetime19. date date9. ;
  /* To have 'date' show as the unformatted value, simply remove the format */
  format date best32. ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment bu i need date to be "1390224849927" how can i get his format?

Comment: I got '1705854850' still not 1390224849927 smth wrong... I am sure about date cause i got  20JAN2014:16:10 from  1390224849927

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting 1390224849927 from. "20JAN2014:16:10"dt will result in 1705853400. SAS date and datetime literals will always show up as numbers unless you specify the format (e.g. date9., datetime.). Can you post the code you wrote that gets you to 1390224849927?